# Java program exit with code "130"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I close a java program in intellJ, the following log appears in the console: 
"Process finished with exit code 130"

[image: screenshot of java program exit code]

Some times, the code is "1".

I know this is the very basic, but I googled Internet and still couldn't find the explanation for the exit code.

What does the code mean? Where can I find the explanation?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: ahh.. so it is bash code, not code in Java program. Thanks!

Comment: If you hit Ctrl+R to rerun the program or forcibly close the program, it's also a exit code 130, it doesn't have to be initialized by Ctrl+C, it's just a OS wide signal code to indicate that the current process has received an Terminated signal.

Answer (score 58):

To steal @Baby 's answer from the comments and formalize it, the 130 exit code is given by [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), and Mendel Cooper's [*Bash-Scripting Guide*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) states that it indicates that the process was terminated by a SIGTERM. Generally this is the user pressing Ctrl-C.

Comment: For me this happened in a docker container when I did `docker logs <containerID>`. Somehow doing ^C on docker logs killed the container!

Comment: I think, the comment from @cst1992 is now fixed. I tried `docker logs`, `docker logs --follow` and `docker attach`. Only the last killed the process that was running. I even tried an endless loop, because docker logs terminates else

Answer (score 2):

This answer is applicable if you want to get the behavior of many native apps that return code 0 after a graceful shutdown.

You can register a hook that performs the graceful shutdown, for example releasing resources retained by the app. If the graceful shutdown succeeds, this hook can also override the exit code to 0. The hook will be called on SIGTERM (happens when the user is pressing Ctrl+C).

```
    Runtime.getRuntime()
        .addShutdownHook(
            new Thread(
                () -> {
                  //graceful shutdown steps
                  Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0); //override the exit code to 0
                }));
```

The solution above will prevent other hooks that may exist to run after this one. It will also prevent files to be deleted that had `.deleteOnExit()` called.

Another approach may be implementing and registering a `SecurityManager` that looks like this:

```
  static class Converting130To0SecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
      if (status == 130) {
        System.exit(0);
      } else {
        super.checkExit(status);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
      // Allow all activities by default
    }
  }

  ...
  System.setSecurityManager(new Converting130To0SecurityManager());
```

Such a security manager will always transform 130 code into 0 irrespectively of the graceful shutdown.