# Getting "Connection Refused" in debugger

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm trying to run this npm script with debugger:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot -d"
  },
```

[image]

here's how it's configured:

[image]

here's how it fails:

[image]

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887088/java-program-exit-with-code-130/32282013

Comment: Yeah, It's the same code, but I'm not pressing CTRL+C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add another script to your `package.json` that looks something like this (and change the configuration to point to it rather than start):

```
"startDebug": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./node_modules/path/to/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot -d"
```

Alternatively, if you don't need debug capabilities, you should be able to **run** (not debug) that configuration without any problem.

Comment: It works for some reason. Please explain the reason.

Comment: Btw, I don't wanna use the run panel for the dev server because that's where I see the elm compiler errors. I don't want those panels mixing up.