# Why does running methods from main result in "Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)"

Tags: java

When I run my application, sometimes nothing appears, and sometimes I get this error message: 
Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT). 
Could anyone identify what is happening here?

```
public class RomanNumberConversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConvertToRomanNumbers convertToRomanNumbers = new ConvertToRomanNumbers();
    convertToRomanNumbers.printInput();
    convertToRomanNumbers.printResult();
}
}
```

--

```
public class ConvertToRomanNumbers {

int inputNumber = ReadInput.readInput();

public void printInput() {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to convert to a roman number:");
    System.out.println("Number: " + inputNumber);
}

public void printResult() {
    System.out.println("Roman number: " + "placeholder");
}
}
```

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class ReadInput {

public static int readInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
}
```

The goal for now is running printInput() and printResult().

Comment: It works fine for me. You may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887088/java-program-exit-with-code-130). Also, this code will First ask for your number and then say "Enter the number..." because the number is asked when the(nonexistent) constructor is called. And you should close the scanner with `scanner.close();`

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I was suspecting it might be a problem that's not code related. Although I am not doing ctrl+C, so problem is not solved yet